# Should there by a [dojo] hitch in my giddy-up?

Tags: javascript, dojo, scope, this

I'm using working on some custom Dojo widgets but keep feeling like I'm the proverbial contortionist that scratches their ear by reaching twice around their head. For some reason my use of `dojo.hitch()` doesn't feel right.

Here's what works:

```
myObject = {
    one: function() {
        promise = new Deferred();
        promise.then(dojo.hitch(this, function() { this.two(); }));
    },
    two: function() {
        // Func 2 stuff
    }
}
myObject.one();
```

...but it seems like that ought to be simpler.

Obviously `promise.then(this.two);` would cause Func 2 to go off prematurely, but the rigmarole with `dojo.hitch(...)` as I've been doing it seems like it should be overkill.

What is the easiest or most proper way to link a method of `this` into a `.then()` function somewhere else in the same object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dojo.hitch(this, function () { this.two(); }))` can definitely be simplified in a couple of ways.

The most literal simplification would be `dojo.hitch(this, this.two)`.

This has the same effect as above, with one less function definition involved, instead passing the `two` function directly to `hitch`.  (`this.two` only references the function, it doesn't execute it, since there are no parentheses after the reference.)

An even more concise simplification would be `dojo.hitch(this, 'two')`.

This is technically slightly different than the previous two, in that it achieves late binding, because `two` will be looked up at the time the generated function is called, whereas in the first two examples, it will be looked up as soon as `hitch` is called to generate the function.

The [hitch and partial tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/hitch/) might also be helpful.